# Find the values of A and B to make a continuous function

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

Let $f$ be a function defined by:

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}(2x+1) & \text{if }  x<a\\
(x^2+3x-5) & \text{if }  a\leq x<b\\
(x-2) &  \text{if }  x\geq b\end{cases}$$

For which values of $a$ and $b$ is the function $f$ continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?

I assume the $\mathbb{R}$ is the Real valued numbers

I was trying to find the limit of the functions and set them to be equal, but it turns out to be the same function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $f$ to be continuous (not differentiable!) all you need to make sure is that it is "connected", i.e.

$$2a+1=a^2+3a-5$$ and $$b^2+3b-5=b-2$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you! I get:
$a=-3$
$a=2$
and
$b=-3$
$b=1$

So these are the values?

Comment: @Akade That looks fine :) Make sure you really understand what you are doing though; try to graph the function for the different values to check whether or not all of them can be used to actually make $f$ "connected".

Comment: @Akade Btw, since you're new (and because I have no shame :P), I wanted to let you know that if you like an answer to your question, you can upvote and/or "accept" it (this is done by clicking the tick under the up/down-vote arrows to the left of the answer) and make the answerer very happy! Cheers!

Comment: Done :). Btw, I am unsure about one more thing. Which one of the two values of a and b should I use for the graph? 2, and 1?

Comment: @Akade Thanks! That was precisely what I wanted you to check in the first comment I wrote. You can graph all three functions at the same time at desmos.com and then change the constants. Good luck!